# Is it possible to simulate a shared folder without changing the name of the computer?

Tags: network-share, share

I need run a local demo of a program that have a harcoded path to a .mbd database in the format:

\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\db.mbd

I can't change the name of local machine because is needed for logging purposes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install VMWare Workstation on your computer.
Create a new virtual machine.
Install Windows.(Remember to use the computername you need)
Problem solved (I hope)

Little bit more work but worth the effort.

;)

Comment: Thanks for your help Clyde, I used Virtualbox with network in bridged mode and works fine !!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Open the Hosts file in notepad.
Add a line which says:

192.168.100.101     NewNameMycomputer

I Hope this works for you.

You can add more lines as above to link your ip address to multiple names.

Comment: Note: change the IP address in the above answer to your local IP address, or to be save, 127.0.0.1 for the loopback adaptor

Comment: Yes i should have mentioned that. Sry but i was in a hurry ;) BTW I think on Windows 7 you might have to fiddle around with security settings on the folder you are sharing if you are asked for a username and password. Maybe something like everyone with all permissions.

Comment: I tried it and actually asked me for username and password, but do not accepted (excuse me my english)

Comment: That is probably because the login for example is not oldmachinename\administrator but newmachinename\administrator, maybe you try to set security/share settings to permit everyone or add a new user corresponding to newmachinename or maybe an anonymous account. Remember it's not an out of the box solution. I guess windows 7 is more frantic about security than Windows xp.

Comment: i posted another solution that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running linux with Samba, you could redirect SharedFolder to another server by setting the "msdfs proxy" parameter to another share (on another computer) in your config.

```
[SharedFolder]
msdfs root = yes
msdfs proxy = \\OtherComputerName\SharedFolder
```

If it's Windows I can't help you with your configuration, search for MSDFS (MicroSoft Distributed File System).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, guided me to find the following information http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Implementing-DFS-Replication.html, however the computer I need to do the test is Windows 7 and I don't found how to apply